# How to split a string into sentences for specific text patterns?

Tags: java, string, split, sentence

I use BreakIterator to split string to sentences, but there is a problem, as shown below.

example of string:

```
"this is first sentence.this is second sentence viva.co.id"
```

The string can not be separated into two, because there is no space between the point and the next sentence. How to slove it?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `String.split(String)` method, which accepts a regular expression and returns an array. It's more flexible than iterators.

```
String text = "this is first sentence.this is second sentence";
String[] sentences = text.split("\\.");
```

Comment: what if there is a url in the senteces, such as viva.co.id?

Comment: In that case, this wouldn't be an appropriate solution.

Comment: is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Not really. The rules of grammar require a space after the period, so when there is no space, that's an input error, and only a user can fix it.